# Does anyone know how to share a photo directly from an email to facebook?

Tags: image, facebook, sdk, share, photo

I have used my personal app id but i won't share it here :D

```
        FB.init({
            appId: '{my app id}',
            xfbml: true,
            status : true,
            version: 'v3.2'
        });
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
```

I have tried using FB.UI share dialog 
I can add more code if necessary for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think this is possible with the JS SDK, you would need to add it to the email with JavaScript. Sharing photos only is not possible at all though, you share an URL that may include a photo in the `og:image` tag. You should use a simple link with `sharer.php` instead.

Edit: As we discussed in the comments, of course you can upload a picture to a Page wall too, and share the URL to that picture.

Comment: I have read about this sharer.php. I mean i tried it and it works perfectly but i really need to use the image from the email the user receives as the chosen image from the story without posting it to a public server or to an url.

Comment: Basically the email should have a share button which will share the image directly to his wall.

Comment: I mean can i add the existing image from email somehow as a parameter to this sharer without posting it.( keep in mind that this image should only be used in the  user personal story line) not in other source.

Comment: that´s not possible, at least not anymore. back then, it was only possible by authorizing a user with the publish_actions permission and by uploading it with the /me/photos endpoint. but again, even that´s not possible anymore.

Comment: your only chance is to use the og:image tag with an existing public image on some server, as i mentioned in my answer

Comment: Yeah i have tried that as well. I mean i have read almost any post on internet. So basically the only option right now for posting an image from an email to facebook is to add it to a public server , website before?

Comment: How about posting the photo directly to your own facebook album?

Comment: you mean, posting the photo on facebook.com? if it´s happening on a page, you can then share the url to that photo.

Comment: Thank you man i have read also on internet about the changes that they made. You've made it very clear to me :P . It was not the fact that i didn't search before but i thought there is somehow a way to do this :D. It was a client request. It's fine that i know it's impossible now. Thank you very much again luschn.

Comment: No worries, you are welcome! I have added the outcome to my answer.